# Twins reproducing with each other ( just hypothetical)

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics, morphology

If 2 twins (look exactly the same and also the genes which control their morphology, behaviour etc. are same and present at the same locus) produce an offspring , will their offspring be exact copy of their parents ?

Sorry . I know its not moral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that identical twins have the same gender and thus cannot reproduce, even if we ignored that issue the offspring would not necessarily be identical to their parents, because people are diploid (have two copies of each gene) and meiosis shuffles genes up somewhat. So for example if the twins are heterozygous for a gene (their two copies are different), with one copy being allele A and the other b, their offspring could be Ab (like their parents), or AA or bb (unlike their parents).

If the twins are monozygous for every gene then their children would indeed be genetically identical to their parents, stray mutations aside. That's what happens with some laboratory animals, that are inbred to the point they are pretty much all genetically identical, and they are monozygous for almost everything.

Comment: ...and inbred individuals may suffer from [inbreeding depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbreeding_depression). There are several potential reasons for such inbreeding depression including the fact that deleterious alleles tend to be slightly recessive (see [Evolution of dominance of alleles](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/evolution-of-dominance-of-alleles))

Answer (score 3):

[Monozygotic twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Monozygotic_(identical)_twins) won't be able to reproduce (naturally), because they are of the same sex. [Dizygotic twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin#Dizygotic_(fraternal)_twins) may or may not be of the same sex, just as regular siblings; genetically speaking, they are just siblings, not twins, so this case is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: @SaraswatiSharma If you consider this answer answered your question, you can click on the checkmark next to the answer to mark the post as being answered.